# Microsoft Azure IoT and Azure IoT devices programing

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services, iot

I am trying to send CLOUD-To-Device messages from back-end using a Xamarin.Android app as back-end, but to do that I need to install some Azure packages that are not being installed and always throwing one exception

> Mono.Android version targeted to: //Android version// and No service reference. Contact the Author.

I have tried different Android versions but it fails with same error.
Can someone help me?

Comment: a [mcve] would be great here!

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Hi, My exact problem is: I want to send a alert to IoT device from Azure IoT Cloud using back-end rather than the Device Manager GUI or Console. For that I choose a Xamarin.Android application as back-end and I am getting that issue while adding the package.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages from the cloud to a device, you need to use Push Notifications via Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).  Since you mentioned Azure Mobile Services, you can use Azure Mobile Services to register the device.  However, I suspect you are using the newer Azure Mobile Apps (which is different!)  A full tutorial is located here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-push/

Comment: Thank you Adrian Hall, I am successful with push notifications via GCM and Azure Mobile Services. My exact problem is: I want to send a alert to IoT device from Azure IoT Cloud using back-end rather than the Device Manager GUI or Console. For that I choose a Xamarin.Android application as back-end and I am getting that issue while adding the package.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The "backend" in this case would be the Azure Mobile Apps and you can send to the notification hub (and hence to your device) using the .NET Notification Hubs SDK or REST.  The "client" would be your Android IoT device.

Comment: Which specific package are you adding?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Devices